# How to calculate integral $\int \frac{dx}{\sqrt{(x^2-B_1^2)(x^2-B_2^2)}}$

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

How to calculate the integral
$$\int \frac{dx}{\sqrt{(x^2-B_1^2)(x^2-B_2^2)}}, $$
where $B_1,B_2 \in \mathbb{R}$ are constants.

I think it involves elliptical integrals and more so, that the integral is the form $sn(x)$. I consulted the book *Hand Book of Elliptical Integrals for Engineers and Scientis (Byrd and Friedman)* but found nothing to help me.

Comment: If $x = B_1 u$, then
$$(x^2 - B_1^2) (x^2 - B_2^2) = C (1 - u^2) (1 - m u^2),$$
which gives one of the standard forms for $F(\phi \mid m)$.

Comment: @Maxim I can express it in terms of the function $sn$? Where $sn$ is the snoidal function.

Comment: In [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3627714), you're asked to show that $\psi = f(\xi)$. Here we find that $\xi = g(\psi)$. What is the relation between $f$ and $g$?

Comment: @Maxim At first I just wanted to solve the integral given here in order to try to solve the ODE given in the other question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $B_1^2 = a$ and $B_2^2 = b$.  Then tables (or software) give:

$$\frac{\sqrt{1-\frac{x^2}{a}} \sqrt{1-\frac{x^2}{b}} F\left(\sin ^{-1}\left(\sqrt{\frac{1}{a}}
   x\right)|\frac{a}{b}\right)}{\sqrt{\frac{1}{a}} \sqrt{\left(a-x^2\right) \left(b-x^2\right)}}$$

Where $F$ denotes an elliptic integral.

Comment: I can express it in terms of the function $sn$?

Comment: If by "$sn$" you mean $\sin$, then no.

Comment: No, sn denotes the Jacobi elliptical function 'snoidal'.

Answer (score 1):

my idea is

$\frac{1}{\sqrt{(x^2-a^2)(x^2-b^2)}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{(x^2-b^2+b^2-a^2)(x^2-b^2)}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{(x^2-b^2)^2 + (x^2-b^2)(b^2-a^2)}}$, then if you choose $t=x^2-b^2$ then $dt=2xdx$ and $x=\sqrt{t+b^2}$ or equivalent $\frac{dt}{2\sqrt{t+b^2}}=dx$ so we need to resolve $\frac{1}{2} \int \frac{dt}{t \sqrt{t+b^2}}$, again if we put $u=\sqrt{t+b^2}$ then $du=\frac{dt}{2\sqrt{t+b^2}}$ and $t=u^2-b^2$ or equivalent $2udu=dt$ and your new integral is
$\int \frac{u}{u^2-b^2}= \int \frac{u-b+b}{(u-b)(u+b)}= \int \frac{du}{u+b} +\int \frac{b}{u^2-b^2}= ...$ and backup with your initial substitution